# How can I make an adjustbox enviroment with margins fit in textwidth?

Tags: minipage, backgrounds, adjustbox, fit

I am trying to create an enviroment with colored background. I have defined it in two ways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\newsavebox{\savedbox}

\newenvironment{colbox1}[1]
    {
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[c]{\textwidth},margin= 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm, bgcolor=#1,env=center}
    }
    {
    \end{adjustbox}
    }


\newsavebox{\savedbox}
\newenvironment{colbox2}[1]
    {
    \newcommand\colboxcolor{#1}
    \begin{lrbox}{\savedbox}
    \begin{minipage}[c]{\textwidth}
    }
    {
    \end{minipage}
    \end{lrbox}
    \begin{center}
      \colorbox{\colboxcolor}{\usebox{\savedbox}}
    \end{center}
    }

\begin{document}
Praesent fermentum erat rhoncus commodo feugiat. Etiam ut metus quis ex vehicula pretium. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi blandit justo a ex imperdiet finibus. Sed libero urna, efficitur vitae eros sagittis, pulvinar tempor eros. Fusce fermentum eget ante vitae auctor. Donec vitae ante accumsan, pretium urna id, lacinia nunc. Aenean augue felis, pretium eget nisi non, bibendum hendrerit urna. Aenean aliquet tempor augue laoreet posuere. Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend. Sed non ante tempus, congue nibh ac, finibus ipsum. Nunc quis pretium elit, a faucibus metus.

\begin{colbox1}{Cornsilk2}
    Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend.
\end{colbox1}

Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi blandit justo a ex imperdiet finibus. Sed libero urna, efficitur vitae eros sagittis, pulvinar tempor eros. Fusce fermentum eget ante vitae auctor. Donec vitae ante accumsan, pretium urna id, lacinia nunc. Aenean augue felis, pretium eget nisi non.

\begin{colbox2}{Cornsilk2}
    Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend.
\end{colbox2}

\end{document}
```

I would like the box to have margin and fit the text width. In `colbox1`, if I write `0.8\textwidth` , I get a box that isn't larger than the text width. However I would like to make the colored background to have exactly the same width of the text. (If someone knows a specific way to create such boxes, I would also love to know.)

See this print image:
[image: pdflatex output]

Comment: Check the tcolorbox-package.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tcolorbox` without frame and `sharp corners` (no. 2 with adjustable margins):

[image: boxes]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{colbox}[1]{colback=#1,colframe=#1,sharp corners}
\newtcolorbox{colbox2}[1]{colback=#1,colframe=#1,left=5mm,right=5mm,top=5mm,bottom=5mm,sharp corners}

\begin{document}
Praesent fermentum erat rhoncus commodo feugiat. Etiam ut metus quis ex vehicula pretium. Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi blandit justo a ex imperdiet finibus. Sed libero urna, efficitur vitae eros sagittis, pulvinar tempor eros. Fusce fermentum eget ante vitae auctor. Donec vitae ante accumsan, pretium urna id, lacinia nunc. Aenean augue felis, pretium eget nisi non, bibendum hendrerit urna. Aenean aliquet tempor augue laoreet posuere. Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend. Sed non ante tempus, congue nibh ac, finibus ipsum. Nunc quis pretium elit, a faucibus metus.

\begin{colbox}{Cornsilk2}
    Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend.
\end{colbox}

Aliquam erat volutpat. Morbi blandit justo a ex imperdiet finibus. Sed libero urna, efficitur vitae eros sagittis, pulvinar tempor eros. Fusce fermentum eget ante vitae auctor. Donec vitae ante accumsan, pretium urna id, lacinia nunc. Aenean augue felis, pretium eget nisi non.

\begin{colbox2}{Cornsilk2}
    Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend.
\end{colbox2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Bobyandbob I don't exactly know which...

Comment: A inner margin between box and (box-)text. Like `margin= 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm` for `adjustbox`.

Comment: @Bobyandbob Now with adjustable margins. But I understood that the OP just desperately tried to get a box with some margin (like my first, not that tight as his second) which fits textwidth.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then you only need to reduce the minipage width by the left and right margin, i.e. use `\textwidth-10mm` instead of `\textwidth`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}% for example text
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newenvironment{colbox1}[1]
    {%
    \begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[c]{\textwidth-10mm},margin= 5mm 5mm 5mm 5mm, bgcolor={#1},env=center}%
    }
    {%
    \end{adjustbox}%
    }

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{colbox1}{Cornsilk2}
    Pellentesque vitae est faucibus, sollicitudin odio in, elementum enim. Maecenas ornare lorem in nunc semper, at malesuada neque eleifend.
\end{colbox1}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot]